# Django : how to make rest api comment with Modelviewset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I tried to use Django's Modelviewset to implement the comment function, but there was a problem.

model :

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add= True)
    content = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null = True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null = True)
    writer =  models.CharField(max_length = 255, null = True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['-id']

class TalkComment(Comment):
    title = "talk"
    post = models.ForeignKey(Talk, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null = True)
```

serializers :

```
class TalkCommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.TalkComment
        fields = '__all__'
```

view :

```
class TalkCommentViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.TalkComment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.TalkCommentSerializer
```

url :

```
router.register(r'talk/(?P<id>\d+)/comment', postview.TalkCommentViewset)
```

```
/api/talk/2/comment/
```

All I wanted was to get the comments from that one post, but all the comments are coming.

How can I get a specific comment from a specific post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting all of the comments cause you initialized `queryset` to return all of the commnents. For getting comments of one specific post you must change the `queryset`. To do that you must override `get_queryset` method (cause you need to get `post_id` argument from request):

```py
class TalkCommentViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.TalkCommentSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        post_id = self.kwargs["id"]
        queryset = TalkComment.objects.filter(post__id=post_id)
        return queryset
```